# Why isn't an http request from an anchor element working correctly?

Tags: javascript

Say I have an HTML page which is reachable at  `http://example.com/redir.php?id=someID`.

I want some JavaScript to, when executed, trigger the downloading of `http://example.com/?file=hgc56gjyd`, and deliver it with the name `newFileName`.

Here's my attempt:

```
var c = document.createElement("a");
c.href = "?file=hgc56gjyd";
c.download = "newFileName";
c.click();
```

But when I execute this, the actual request made is to `http://example.com/redir.php?file=hgc56gjyd`. Notice the added `'redir.php'`. This URL is incorrect and the downloaded file is empty. But changing of a name works in this case.

If I write out the entire URL or with "/" or "./" (in the beginning):

```
c.href = "http://example.com/?file=hgc56gjyd"
c.href = "/?file=hgc56gjyd"
c.href = "./?file=hgc56gjyd"
```

then the `download` attribute doesn't take effect so the resulting file is not renamed to `newFileName`.

How can I trigger a request to the correct URI, while getting the functionality of `download`?

This is in Chrome.

Comment: You can update `window.location` directly.

Comment: Is the link on a different domain? I think there are restrictions of naming when you are on a different domain.

Comment: If to delete "redir.php" from location then link will be not working. And I want to do this without changing location anyway.

Comment: All links are on the same domain.

Comment: How'bout "/?file=hgc56gjyd"?

Comment: Please inspect the download's response headers. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes): "If the HTTP header `Content-Disposition:` gives a different filename than this attribute, the HTTP header takes priority over this attribute."

Comment: There is a Content-Disposition header. But changing of a name really works if to use "?file=hgc56gjyd" without "/". With "/" in the beginning changing doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: As explained by T.J. Crowder: different URL, different headers.

Answer (score 1):

By doing this:

```
c.href = "?file=hgc56gjyd";
```

in a document at `http://example.com/redir.php?id=someID`, you're effectively doing this:

```
c.href = "http://example.com/redir.php?file=hgc56gjyd";
// Note ---------------------^^^^^^^^^
```

If you want it to be `http://example.com/?file=hgc56gjyd` instead, you don't have to use an absolute path — absolute paths *within* a site are a Bad Thing™ :-) — just use either a leading `/` or a leading `./`:

```
c.href = "/?file=hgc56gjyd";
// -------^
```

or

```
c.href = "./?file=hgc56gjyd";
// -------^^
```

Use the former (`/`) if you want to go to the domain root regardless of the URL of the page the link is on; use the latter (`./`) if you just want the default URL at the level of the page that the link is on. In your example, those are the same thing, but they wouldn't be if this were on a page at `http://example.com/somethinghere/redir.php?id=someID`.

Live Example (with `https://stacksnippets.net` instead of `http://example.com` and `js` insead of `redir.php`):

```js
console.log("Location: " + location);

// Your current code
var c = document.createElement("a");
c.href = "?file=hgc56gjyd";
c.download = "newFileName";
// Notice the `js` on this (which is like your redir.php)
console.log("Your Link:" + c.href);

// The corrected code (#1
var c2 = document.createElement("a");
c2.href = "/?file=hgc56gjyd";
c2.download = "newFileName";
// Notice there's no `js` now
console.log("Fix1:     " + c2.href);

// The corrected code (#2
var c3 = document.createElement("a");
c3.href = "./?file=hgc56gjyd";
c3.download = "newFileName";
// Notice there's no `js` now
console.log("Fix2:     " + c3.href);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

In the question and in the comments, you've said that just using `"?file=hgc56gjyd"` "works" in terms of renaming the file (but not downloading it, you get an empty file instead) but using the correct path (an absolute path or either of the solutions above) "doesn't work" because it uses the name from the server instead. But the difference isn't the path itself, it's what the server is sending in response to the path: The `Content-Disposition` header's filename wins over anything you put in the `download` attribute. The actual download script (at `/`) sends it. Clearly the `redir.php` script doesn't.

The solution is to shift the filename aspect to the **server**, being sure to return the document with this header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=newFileName
```

For instance, if the download is processed by PHP code, you'd do:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

<?php
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=newFileName")
```

That way, the **server** is telling the browser what the name should be. The browser is still allowed to ignore it (but in my experience generally uses it).

If all of that fails (for instance, because you can't change the server's code sending that response), there's one more option: Use a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) (this is [surprisingly well supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls)). Here's an example using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch):

```
// In an event handler...
fetch("./?file=hgc56gjyd")
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
        }
        return response.blob();
    })
    .then(blob => {
        var c = document.createElement("a");
        c.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        c.download = "bar.json";
        c.click();
    })
    .catch(e => {
        alert(e.message);
    });
```

That successfully uses the `download` name.

If you can't do **that**, I'm afraid I think you're truly out of luck. :-|